# select numeric new columns using union query

Tags: sql-server, union

I have written a union query in sql server 2008. Below is the query:

```html
select cast(i.AMT_SETT as decimal(10,2)) as AMT_SETT 
from  DIB_ERECON_INSIGHT_VISA i

union 
select NULL as AMT_SETT from DIB_ERECON_TRAN_DETAILS d 
where d.channeltype = 'VISA' and cast(fieldno_1 as date) = '18-Apr-2017' and 
not exists(
              select 1 from DIB_ERECON_INSIGHT_VISA i 
              where i.STAN= d.fieldno_38 and replace(d.fieldno_39,':','') = i.TIME_LOC_TRAN and 
              cast(i.Amount as numeric(18,0)) = cast(d.fieldno_31 as numeric(18,0))
              )
```

I get this error:

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

If I try `''` instead of `null` in the second query for `AMTT_SETT` column I get the same error

Comment: What result do you get if you execute the first query of the `UNION`?

Comment: Error from your first select statement, some of the value is string instead of numeric

Comment: did you find any row which return 0 with ISNUMERIC() use?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure that all values in AMT_SETT,Amount and fieldno_31 columns are numeric values. you can use the function ISNUMERIC(yourcolumn) to detect all non numeric values stored in your columns.

Comment: the column is numeric i checked

Comment: its now working fine in sql database but when i export it to excel the decimals are automatically trimmed is there any way to stop it? Is that issue of excel  or data?

Comment: how did you do the export operation ?

Comment: using asp.net application button click event

Answer (score 1):

Error from your first select statement, some of the value is string instead of numeric, please have a look in data and check which row has non numeric value.

You can easily get that row as below:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ISNUMERIC(ColumnName)=0
```